# Modal form, javascript, ajax y php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Hay tres pasos que estoy haciendo:

HTML > JavaScript > PHP. En uno de ellos me estoy equivocando y sospecho que es en el JavaScript.

Mi HTML: Clase Modal. Aparentemente funciona:

```
<!-- Modal para solicitar evaluación de caso -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModalEvaluacion" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form id="evaModal">            
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Cerrar</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Solicitar evaluación:</h4>
                </div>
                <!-- Campos que pertenecen a solicitar una cita para evaluación de servicio -->
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="evaNombre" id="evaNombre" placeholder="Nombre" required />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="evaApellido" id="evaApellido" placeholder="Apellido" required />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="evaTelefono" id="evaTelefono" placeholder="Teléfono" required />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="evaEmail" id="evaEmail" placeholder="Email" required />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                            <textarea class="form-control" name="evaComentario" id="evaComentario" placeholder="Comentario"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <select class="form-control" name="evaServicio" id="evaServicio" required >
                                <option>Seleccione motivo</option>
                                <option value="1">Análisis emprarial</option>
                                <option value="2">Desarrollo Web</option>
                                <option value="3">Web Hosting</option>
                                <option value="4">Posicionamiento Web</option>
                                <option value="5">Email Marketing</option>
                                <option value="6">Videos y Animaciones 3D</option>
                                <option value="7">Otro</option>
                             </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <input type="hidden" name="evaUrl" id="evaUrl" value="/" />
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Paso a JavaScript. Creo que aquí está el error, pero no logro atajarlo.

```
$('#myModalEvaluacion').validate({
        submitHandler: function(form){
            $('#myModalEvaluacion').modal('hide');
            //Variables
            var evaNombre = $('#evaNombre').val();
            var evaApellido = $('#evaApellido').val();
            var evaTelefono = $('#evaTelefono').val();
            var evaEmail = $('#evaEmail').val();
            var evaComentario = $('#evaComentario').val();
            var evaServicio = $('#evaServicio').val();

            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "/ingresarEva.php",
                data: {
                    query: "quote",
                    evaNombre: evaNombre,
                    evaApellido: evaApellido,
                    evaTelefono: evaTelefono,
                    evaEmail: evaEmail,
                    evaComentario: evaComentario,
                    evaServicio: evaServicio,
                }
            })
            .done(function(){
                bootbox.alert("Gracias por escribirnos. Recibimos su información y pronto estaremos en contacto.", function() {console.log("Alert Callback");})
                $('#evaNombre').val('');
                $('#evaApellido').val('');
                $('#evaTelefono').val('');
                $('#evaEmail').val('');
                $('#evaComentario').val('');
                $('#evaServicio').val('');
            })
        }
    });
```

Y el código PHP de insertar. Funciona pero no está llegando hasta allí.

```
mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO Cita VALUES ('$evaEmail', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '$evaNombre', '$evaApellido', '$evaTelefono', '$evaServicio', '$evacomentario');");
mysqli_close($link); // Cerramos la conexion con la base de datos
echo 'Los datos han sido insertados en la base de datos';
```

¿Donde estoy cometiendo el error en el paso de variables?

Comment: has probado debugear con `console.log("bien")`, solo es para revisar que este tomando los valores y este entrando al código de validar el formulario

Comment: Tras una inspección rápida del código, me parece que tu botón de HTML no está ejecutando ninguna acción, por ende no se ejecuta nada de lado del servidor. Te recomiendo utilizar `console.log` para escribir mensajes en la consola. Si utilizas Firefox y Chrome, presiona la tecla F12 para que veas la consola JavaScript y el tab de Redes (Network) para que veas si se han lanzado peticiones al servidor, qué datos se han enviado y qué ha respondido el servidor. Todo eso te ayudará a revisar y comprender el problema y proveer una solución.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza tiene razón, el botón no tiene, de paso te recomiendo que envies un JSON de los datos, se veria mejor el codigo, y es mas practico

Answer (score 1):

Pude resolver el problema, ahora tengo un detalle con la alerta de Bootbox pero le dí la vuelta al script y funciona correctamente.

```
 <!-- MANEJO MODAL -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function(){
          $('#myEva').validate({
            submitHandler: function( form ){
                $('#myEva').modal('hide');
                $.post('ingresarEva.php',$('#myEva').serialize() + '&query=myEva')
               .done(function(data){
                   if( data == 'true' ){
                       bootbox.alert("Hello world!", function() {Example.show("Hello world callback");});
                       $('.form-control').val('');
                    } else {
                    bootbox.alert("Hello world!", function() {Example.show("Hello world callback");});
                    }
                   })
               }
           });  
          });
        </script>
        <!-- FIN DEL MANEJO MODAL -->
```

Comment: Hola Akyna, agrega esto en otra pregunta, creo que funcionaría más, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Tu error esta en el PHP, en el INSERT no especificas en que campos vas a insertar los valores. Tu codigo es así:

```
mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO Cita VALUES ('$evaEmail', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '$evaNombre', '$evaApellido', '$evaTelefono', '$evaServicio', '$evacomentario');");
mysqli_close($link); // Cerramos la conexion con la base de datos
 echo 'Los datos han sido insertados en la base de datos';
```

Cuando debería ser así:

```
mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO Cita ('email', 'fecha', 'nombre', 'apellido', 'telefono', 'servicio', 'comentario') VALUES ('$evaEmail', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '$evaNombre', '$evaApellido', '$evaTelefono', '$evaServicio', '$evacomentario')");
mysqli_close($link); // Cerramos la conexion con la base de datos
echo 'Los datos han sido insertados en la base de datos';
```